# Can't figure out how to fix model in blender

Tags: modeling

I have designed a fish using blender and I'm having trouble with the part of the mesh where the fins meet the body. I assume I need to fix the ngons but it just pushes it further up the side of the model. I have a subsurf modifier and morror modifier not yet applied, fyi. Looking and the wire mesh the surface above the part where the fins meet the body is pulled away from the center of the face. I tried a few different approaches including making the face/s non-ngon. Any Help is greatly appreciated.[image: Tears/ripples]

Comment: Consider posting a .blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for closer inspection (just edit this into your question). Then those who would like to help can take a closer look.

Comment: I got help elsewhere. They suggested I connect the geometry arcoss the model.

Comment: http://community.cgcookie.com/t/issue-with-mesh/4510